# Tensorflow Federated TFF still a Simulation Environment?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

TensorFlow Federated (TFF) is an open-source framework for ML and other computations on decentralized data.

As per Stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323598/is-tensorflow-federated-learning-only-for-simulating-federated-learning-on-one-m)

> TFF only provides a simulation environment for use in Federated
> Learning (FL) research. There is not yet a "real world" FL deployment
> platform.

But, tensorFlow release history shows that now there are many release versions for TF 2.x as well.

```
https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/releases
```

Can anybody comment, if TFF is still or simulation environment or can be used as "real world" FL deployment platform?

Answer (score 3):

At this time, TensorFlow Federated does not have out-of-the-box support for what would generally be considered production federated learning. A production-level deployment runtime still needs to be built.

For different flavors of federated learning this maybe easier or harder.

It may be possible to create a system for *cross-silo FL* using the executor components already available in TensorFlow Federated. Particularly it maybe possible to extend and build something on top of the remote execution stack (e.g. [`tff.framework.RemoteExecutor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/framework/RemoteExecutor))

However for *cross-device FL* it maybe signifcantly more work, as there are no integrations or components for deploying and execution computations on mobile operating systems (iOS, Android, etc) yet.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zachary Garrett.

Do you think OpenMined/PySyft with Pytorch is little matured as compared to Tensorflow Federated(TFF)?
I am trying to develop a POC for my University. I have phishing dataset and want to apply Deep Learning with Federated Learning on this phishing dataset.
Can you suggest if should choose TFF or PySyft?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough experience with PySyft to be able to make a knowledgeable comparison. If the data is already gathered in a centralized place, it sounds like a production deployment isn't necessary, rather capabilities to simulate the environment and train a model would suffice? TensorFlow Federated definitely aims to support this kind of research direction.